# Tag synonym request: chroot and chroot-jail

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[chroot](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/chroot) and [chroot-jail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/chroot-jail) seem to refer to the same thing. A lot of questions are tagged with both.

Answer (score 6):

The annoying bit is that `jail` has a specific meaning on [FreeBSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail) that that is a kind of virtualization, somewhat similar to [LXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC).  It looks like 90% of the `chroot-jail` questions are tagged Linux because many people have confused the term.

I think that we need to go through [jails](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jails), [jail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jail), and [chroot-jail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/chroot-jail) tags.  All three should be completely removed and in the cases where appropriate we add a tag like [freebsd-jail](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/freebsd-jail).  For the questions not actually about a freebsd jail we retag as [chroot](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/chroot).

I am not sure a synonym is appropriate.  I hope if we eliminate the tag it won't come back?

There are also a smattering of questions that don't seem to be about a chroot setup, or freebsd-jails, and instead asking about some general application virtualization type setup.  We probably can't just do a mass-retag.  People will need to look at the questions individual and re-tag as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of FreeBSD jails, but I've never seen them referred to as a "chroot jail", and I didn't spot any questions using the tag to mean that. Should I start manually retagging questions if this shouldn't be done with a mass-retag?

Comment: Seems like chroot-jail should be deleted, with questions retagged to "chroot" or "jail" as is appropriate.